# How to set TransactionScope to Read Uncommited by default

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

My project use dbml to access database with linq to sql. It uses transaction at several operation which is required.

As the database is growing I face the following errors:

1. **Timeout expired**. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
2. **Transaction (Process ID 82) was deadlocked** on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction

There are thousands of linq queries spread over the project. So I can not put `TransactionSope` code to all select queries as it is time consuming.

Is there any way so i can set default Transaction IsolationLevel in dbml so that it reads uncommitted and do not get in deadlock.

Please let me know if you have any questions on the issue.

Comment: That sounds like using a flamethrower to kill a fly - it may work, but it's hardly the best way to do things (and it may not relieve the deadlocks, if the deadlocks are between two statements that are performing `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` statements).

Comment: Is there any way instead of using transaction in linq ? something like we use "With NoLock" in sql statuements. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following call before query execution should work ..

```
dataContext.ExecuteCommand("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED")
```

You can execute this once after initialising the dataContext 
OR

Implement an Extension method which calls datacontext ExecuteCommand once for setting transaction isolation level as above and then once for actual command execution.